# Content-Encoding metadata for Amazon S3 object causing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to serve compressed images from Amazon S3. I'm getting following error in Google Chrome when I set `Content-Encoding:gzip` for particular S3 Object.

```
This site can’t be reached
The web page at http://bucket-name.amazonaws.com/E872EA6505/images/1519795859_edition_3_buy_1_large.jpg might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

[image]

When I delete `Content-Encoding` metadata it works fine.

Comment: Setting `Content-Encoding: gzip` means that *you* have gzipped the content, yourself, before uploading it to S3... but you didn't mention doing that.  Did you gzip the file, remove the `.gz` extension, and then upload?

Comment: Also, you should find that gzip is not really appropriate for JPEG images, because it does not compress them very much at all.  The gzip algorithm allows a perfect reconstruction of the original object -- true, fully-reversible, *lossless* "compression."  Usually, when people speak of "image compression," they are actually speaking of *data reduction*, which is *lossy* --
it permanently removes some of the finer detail from the image -- a tradeoff of size and perfect reproduction.  All JPEG images are already necessarily at least somewhat by definition, but this can be done more aggressively.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot if i didn't gzip before i upload what settings should i use to accompany gzip

Comment: @CodeGuru S3 serves objects exactly as they were stored -- it doesn't perform any transformations (like gzipping).  If you want S3 to serve a gzipped representation, it needs to be uploaded already gzipped.  Not sure what you mean by "accompany gzip".